# android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout failed to instantiate

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to use a `GridLayout` in my project, but ideally with the Android Support Library so I can target lower versions of the API. When I drag a `GridLayout` into the graphical layout designer, a message pops up asking explaining I need a compatibility library for API versions older than 14, and asks if I want to install this library. I hit "Install" and let Eclipse do its thing, but an error shows up in the Eclipse graphical layout designer:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout See the Error Log ( Window > Show View) for more details."
```

(here is [screenshot](http://i50.tinypic.com/14b448o.png) )

From the error log, `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` failed to instantiate.

Comment: Make sure you have added the GridLayout library project in your project as library.

Comment: Also as you import GridLayout  library into your workspace make sure you copy that library project into your workspace also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have added the GridLayout library project in your project as library.

Try out as below to import the library project of `GridLayout`

`File->Import->Existing Android code into workspace` Specify `android-sdk-[path]/extras/android/support/v7/gridlayout`

Make sure You import and copy the `GridLayout` project as an Android library project into your workspace.

After import library project add it into your project as library as below:

`Right click your Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export` where tick mark all option.

Comment: Exception raised during rendering: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.resolveSizeAndState(III) got this err google it with no success

Comment: @kaushik what is your issue ?

Comment: i dont understand the msg showing in eclipse when i add a gridlayout into xml

Comment: @kaushik Please post your issue as question. Make sure you have added the `support.v4.view.ViewCompat` library in your project.

Comment: Thanks alot @GrIsHu i have tried this before not working but after your answer its doing just fine ..dont know its a maricle or something  else...

Answer (score 3):

This is how i solved the problem in Eclipse...

Right Click on your Support Libraries ( in my Case: android-support-v7-appcompat / android-support-v7-gridlayout) go to -> Java Compiler -> set Compiler compliance level to 1.7

And do the same to your Project....

After that Restart Eclipse -> Clean -> Build

And now it should work....

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem recently after Android 6 (23) did not display a linear layout correctly.  I tried using android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout but it failed to instantiate in Eclipse

None of the solutions suggested worked for me.
Finally I 'fixed' it by installing AndroidStudio V2 and using it there.
Note: Initially it did not work in AndroidStudio because the path to one of its resources was >240 chars.  I had to move my AndroidStudio work space to solve that.

That suggests that it may be a similar problem in Eclipse, but without the helpful error message.

I tried just moving the V7 library to a shorter dir path but that did not work.
However the library path appears to be relative and the shorter path was referenced by ../../../../   etc so result may still be >240

I have not tried moving all my projects to a shorter path.  Perhaps some can try that and report.